Can a .NET 7 API Consumer choose which properties to return?
Does the API framework in .NET have a built-in mechanism for choosing which properties of the return object to return? For example if my object is Vehicle { Color = "Red", Type = "Truck", Wheels = 4 } and I only wanted to return the properties Color and Wheels, I may want to do something like call
GET - https://server/api/vehicles/1?prop1=color&prop2=wheels

And the framework would interpret that and know to return { color = "red, wheels = 4 }, ideally of course.
Obviously I can manually check for any specified properties in the request and only populate those, null the rest, and format the json serializer to not return null properties.
The question is the a .NET native way or NuGet package that someone has written so that you don't have to individually code each method?

.NET doesn't specify what protocol is used by your application or the meaning of request parameters and bodies. That's the job of application-level protocols like GraphQL, OData, or your own custom code. There are packages that implement GraphQL like Hot Chocolate

You added properties to your URL (prop1, prop2) and need to add a route for the properties.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-up-conventional-route

I think the answer is ASP.NET Core OData
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio

@YohancefChin no, it's definitely not. OData never caught on and the ASP.NET Core implementation has .... issues and quirks. By now, only Microsoft Graph and SAP use it. GraphQL on the other hand is a de-facto standard supported across all web-related technologies. Check for example the Azure Data Builder tool which, despite the name, can generate GraphQL APIs for any database using HotChocolate

@YohancefChin to put it another way, I regret ever using OData to create my own data services

OData can achieve the functionality you want. You can add OData capabilities to your api by including the Microsoft.OData.Core NuGet package in your project.
Here's an article explaining how to set it up for .NET 6 but the steps are the same for .NET 7: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/up-running-w-odata-in-asp-net-6/
First enable OData in your Program.cs by calling: AddOData() like so:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy()); // <-- add this

Your web api is now OData enabled! Next tell the framework which Controller methods should allow OData style queries by adding [EnableQuery] attribute to it:
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery] // <-- add this
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}

Finally, you can select which properties you want returned by specifying them in the query params like so: $select=property_name
Here's me fetching this dummy data without the select filter:

And here it is with the addition of the select filter $select=TemperatureC


I can't comment on the current popularity of OData and its pros/cons vs GraphQL. But I'm more familiar with OData so I shared instructions for that.

It seems to (still) work in .NET8, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio#example-6-retrieve-customer-names-only    Because .net7 is End of Support May 14, 2024
